# How to group the data as per quarter using date in Amcharts 4

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I am using amcharts 4 to apply grouping on date axis this is my code

```js
 am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

    // Create chart instance
    var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

    // Add data
    chart.data = [
  {
    "EntityID": 43,
    "EntityName": "ALRAJHI",
    "Labels": "Q1-20",
    "ForYear": 2020,
    "FiscalPeriodValue": "Q1",
    "ForDate": "2020-03-31T00:00:00",
    "Book Value (BV)": 12.3966855
  },
  {
    "EntityID": 43,
    "EntityName": "ALRAJHI",
    "Labels": "Q2-20",
    "ForYear": 2020,
    "FiscalPeriodValue": "Q2",
    "ForDate": "2020-06-30T00:00:00",
    "Book Value (BV)": 12.9825065
  },
  {
    "EntityID": 43,
    "EntityName": "ALRAJHI",
    "Labels": "Q3-20",
    "ForYear": 2020,
    "FiscalPeriodValue": "Q3",
    "ForDate": "2020-09-30T00:00:00",
    "Book Value (BV)": 13.7297505
  },
  {
    "EntityID": 43,
    "EntityName": "ALRAJHI",
    "Labels": "Q4-20",
    "ForYear": 2020,
    "FiscalPeriodValue": "Q4",
    "ForDate": "2020-12-31T00:00:00",
    "Book Value (BV)": 14.5296295
  },
  {
    "EntityID": 43,
    "EntityName": "ALRAJHI",
    "Labels": "Q1-21",
    "ForYear": 2021,
    "FiscalPeriodValue": "Q1",
    "ForDate": "2021-03-31T00:00:00",
    "Book Value (BV)": 14.80553625
  },
  {
    "EntityID": 43,
    "EntityName": "ALRAJHI",
    "Labels": "Q2-21",
    "ForYear": 2021,
    "FiscalPeriodValue": "Q2",
    "ForDate": "2021-06-30T00:00:00",
    "Book Value (BV)": 14.91751775
  },
  {
    "EntityID": 43,
    "EntityName": "ALRAJHI",
    "Labels": "Q3-21",
    "ForYear": 2021,
    "FiscalPeriodValue": "Q3",
    "ForDate": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
    "Book Value (BV)": 15.9023115
  },
  {
    "EntityID": 43,
    "EntityName": "ALRAJHI",
    "Labels": "Q4-21",
    "ForYear": 2021,
    "FiscalPeriodValue": "Q4",
    "ForDate": "2021-12-31T00:00:00",
    "Book Value (BV)": 16.820391
  },
  {
    "EntityID": 43,
    "EntityName": "ALRAJHI",
    "Labels": "Q1-22",
    "ForYear": 2022,
    "FiscalPeriodValue": "Q1",
    "ForDate": "2022-03-31T00:00:00",
    "Book Value (BV)": 17.96029475
  },
  {
    "EntityID": 43,
    "EntityName": "ALRAJHI",
    "Labels": "Q2-22",
    "ForYear": 2022,
    "FiscalPeriodValue": "Q2",
    "ForDate": "2022-06-30T00:00:00",
    "Book Value (BV)": 18.85329575
  },
  {
    "EntityID": 43,
    "EntityName": "ALRAJHI",
    "Labels": "Q3-22",
    "ForYear": 2022,
    "FiscalPeriodValue": "Q3",
    "ForDate": "2022-09-30T00:00:00",
    "Book Value (BV)": 19.9003095
  },
  {
    "EntityID": 43,
    "EntityName": "ALRAJHI",
    "Labels": "Q4-22",
    "ForYear": 2022,
    "FiscalPeriodValue": "Q4",
    "ForDate": "2022-12-31T00:00:00",
    "Book Value (BV)": 20.93125875
  }
]

    // Create axes
    var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
    dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
    dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 20;

    // Custom function to create axis labels for quarters and years
    function createAxisLabels(date) {
      var year = date.getFullYear();
      var quarter = Math.floor((date.getMonth() + 3) / 3); // Calculate the quarter (1, 2, 3, 4)
      return "Q" + quarter + "-" + year; // Example: "Q1-2020"
    }

    // Set up dateAxis to use custom labels
    dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey("month", "MM");
    dateAxis.periodChangeDateFormats.setKey("month", "MM");
    dateAxis.adapter.add("getFormattedLabel", function (text, target, key) {
      if (target.dataItem && target.dataItem.dateX instanceof Date) {
        return createAxisLabels(target.dataItem.dateX);
      }
      return text;
    });

    var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

    // Create series
    function createSeries(field, name) {
      var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
      series.dataFields.valueY = field;
      series.dataFields.dateX = "ForDate";
      series.name = name;
      series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{dateX}: [b]{valueY}[/]";
      series.strokeWidth = 2;
      series.columns.template.strokeWidth = 0;
    }

    createSeries("Book Value (BV)", "Series #1");

    // Create ranges
    function createRange(from, to, label) {
      var range = dateAxis.axisRanges.create();
      range.date = from;
      range.endDate = to;
      range.label.text = label;
      range.label.paddingTop = 40;
      range.label.location = 0.5;
      range.label.horizontalCenter = "middle";
      range.label.fontWeight = "bolder";
      range.grid.disabled = true;
    }

    createRange(new Date(2020, 0, 1), new Date(2020, 2, 30), "Q1");
    createRange(new Date(2020, 3, 1), new Date(2020, 5, 31), "Q2");
    createRange(new Date(2020, 6, 1), new Date(2020, 8, 30), "Q3");
    createRange(new Date(2020, 9, 1), new Date(2020, 11, 31), "Q4");

    // Custom function to create grid lines for the end of each year
    function createRangeGrid(date) {
      var range = dateAxis.axisRanges.create();
      range.date = date;
      range.grid.strokeOpacity = 0.2;
      range.tick.disabled = false;
      range.tick.strokeOpacity = 0.3;
      range.tick.length = 60;
    }

    createRangeGrid(new Date(2020, 12, 30));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

The first axis is creating as per 1 , 2 , 3 and than Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4 grouped together

I want to have Q1 , Q2 , Q3, Q4 below each bar and grouped together by the year.

If my data is for fiscalPeriod Quarter so i want the desired outpur as mentioned above , but if the data is for year based , than i want to group the data just based on years .

in my dataset if the labels is having Q it means the data based on quarters , if it does not have Q it means the data is based on years

Below is the image which shows my desired output

[image]